# Next.js Middleware Error :- [Error: The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'crypto' module]

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am new to next.js and typescript and i am really fustrated with this problem as its been 4 days and i can't find a solution.. please if anyone knows the cause and problem help me with the solution. It will be so helpfull . Thanks

-- This is my middleware.ts

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import clientPromise from "./database/db";

interface RequestWithUserId extends NextRequest {
  userId: string;
}

export async function middleware(req: RequestWithUserId) {
  try {
    const mongoClient = await clientPromise;
    const token = req.cookies.get("jwt")?.value;

    if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
    }

    const decodedToken: any = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);

    const userId = decodedToken._id;

    const checkUserExists = await mongoClient
      .db()
      .collection("user")
      .findOne({ _id: userId });

    if (!checkUserExists) {
      return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
    }

    req.userId = userId;
    return NextResponse.next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("miidleware error", err);
    NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: "/api/addToCart",
};
```

Answer (score 9):

**jsonwebtoken** doesn't support running on Edge environment as it's different from Node.js. You could use [jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose) which supports Vercel's Edge Runtime instead of **jsonwebtoken**.

Comment: more about this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38227

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me | Pages router

First:

```
npm install jose
```

Create middleware.js file in src/middleware.js

```
import { isAuthenticated } from './lib/jwtTokenControl'

// Limit the middleware to paths starting with `/api/`
// matcher: ['/about/:path*', '/dashboard/:path*'],
export const config = {
  matcher: '/api/v1/:function*'
}

export async function middleware(request) {
  const result = await isAuthenticated(request)

  if (!result) {
    return Response.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid token. Paths starting with `/api/v1/`' }, { status: 401 })
  }
}
```

Create src/lib/jwtTokenControl.js file

```
import * as jose from 'jose'

const jwtConfig = {
  secret: new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_JWT_SECRET),
}

export const isAuthenticated = async req => {
  let token = req.headers.get('authorization') || req.headers.get('Authorization')

  if (token) {
    try {
      if (token.startsWith('Bearer')) {
        token = token.replace('Bearer ', '')
      }

      const decoded = await jose.jwtVerify(token, jwtConfig.secret)

      if (decoded.payload?._id) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('isAuthenticated error: ', err)

      return false
    }
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on @Nijat's answer that served as a good base for me.

If you are using Next-Auth, here is what I did to plug into what they expose. The important thing here is the middleware and the [...nextauth].ts is using the same decode function that uses jose.jwtVerify. And then to eliminate jsonwebtoken completely I modified the encode function to use jose.SignJWT.

src/middleware.ts:

```
import { NextRequestWithAuth, withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';
import { NextFetchEvent } from 'next/server';
import jwtConfig from './config/jwt';

export default withAuth(
  function middleware(request: NextRequestWithAuth, event: NextFetchEvent) {},
  {
    jwt: {
      decode: jwtConfig.decode,
    },
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ req, token }) => {
        console.log(token);
        return !!token;
      },
    },
  }
);

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api/auth|auth|static|_next/static|_next/image|images|favicon.ico|health).*)', // for me, all api routes should be blocked except /api/auth
  ],
};
```

src/config/jwt.ts

```
import { JWT, JWTDecodeParams, JWTEncodeParams, getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import * as jose from 'jose';

const encodedSecret = new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET);

const encode = async (params: JWTEncodeParams): Promise<string> => {
  const signedToken = await new jose.SignJWT(params.token)
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'HS256' })
    .sign(encodedSecret);
  if (!signedToken) {
    throw new Error('Failed to sign token');
  }
  return signedToken;
};

const decode = async (params: JWTDecodeParams): Promise<JWT | null> => {
  if (!params.token) {
    throw new Error('Failed to verify token');
  }

  let token = params.token;

  if (params.token.startsWith('Bearer')) {
    token = params.token.replace('Bearer ', '');
  }

  try {
    const decoded = await jose.jwtVerify(token, jwtConfig.encodedSecret);

    if (!decoded.payload) {
      throw new Error('Failed to verify token');
    }

    return decoded.payload;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error(`${error}`);
  }
};

export const jwtConfig = {
  encode,
  decode,
};

export default jwtConfig;
```

and lastly, src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```
import { JWT, JWTDecodeParams, JWTEncodeParams, getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import * as jose from 'jose';

const encodedSecret = new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET);
const encode = async (params: JWTEncodeParams): Promise<string> => {
  const signedToken = await new jose.SignJWT(params.token) // details to  encode in the token
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'HS256' }) // algorithm
    .sign(encodedSecret); // secretKey generated from previous step
  if (!signedToken) {
    throw new Error('Failed to sign token');
  }
  return signedToken;
};

const decode = async (params: JWTDecodeParams): Promise<JWT | null> => {
  if (!params.token) {
    throw new Error('Failed to verify token');
  }

  let token = params.token;

  if (params.token.startsWith('Bearer')) {
    token = params.token.replace('Bearer ', '');
  }

  try {
    const decoded = await jose.jwtVerify(token, jwtConfig.encodedSecret);

    if (!decoded.payload) {
      throw new Error('Failed to verify token');
    }

    return decoded.payload;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error(`${error}`);
  }
};

export const jwtConfig = {
  encode,
  decode,
  encodedSecret,
};

export default jwtConfig;
```